# changed user path and lost aliases in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, path, alias, git

I reinstalled mountain lion recently and had to reset my git path. Everything was working fine until I realised I had to do it for every project so I tried to change the default system path by `sudo bash -c '( echo /usr/local/git/bin > /etc/paths.d/git )'`

Apparently I should have left it alone as I don't really know what I'm doing. My command prompt is now `unknown-00-26-bb-0e-a8-1f:~ mantismamita$` (mantismamita is my username so that part is normal) and I have lost access to my aliases located in `.bash_profile` I'm also back to square one with my original problem as my git path is no longer correct. I should mention that I'm at a different IP address as I'm on holiday so that may have influenced the prompt.

I would be eternally grateful if someone could help me get out of this muddle.

Comment: You need to restore /etc/paths.d/git from a backup or update OSX from the combo update as you have overwritten the Apple supplied file. The command should have had >> rather than >

Comment: so I could just run the combo update here : http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1659 ? Or would I have to do something to restore the original path?

Comment: There is no `/etc/paths.d/git` on a plain installation so `>` or `>>` doesn't matter. I'm quite sure that the problem doesn't relate to the git path thing. Do you have network environments defined in Preferences?

Comment: no, the network I'm on is listed under system preferences but I haven't done anything to define it. Then again, I never had problems with my aliases other times I switched networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are not related. What you're seeing is the default bash prompt, which is defined in /etc/bashrc:

```
$ grep PS1=  /etc/bashrc
PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
```

From the bash man page:

```
 \h     the hostname up to the first `.'
 \u     the username of the current user
 \W     the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
```

What's happened is that your hostname is not being set correctly. It related to your network settings. It was discussed on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/318509/hostname-issue-in-mac-os-x-lion

And on the /etc/paths.d/git file, what you did is correct. If you have git installed in /usr/local/git/bin, then the install usually creates that file for you. But the contents are trivial, so you can create it yourself. It should have a single line, containing the path to the bin directory you want added to PATH for all users:

```
$ ls -l /etc/paths.d/git
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  19 Sep 17  2009 /etc/paths.d/git
$ od -ta /etc/paths.d/git
0000000    /   u   s   r   /   l   o   c   a   l   /   g   i   t   /   b
0000020    i   n  nl
0000023
$ wc -l /etc/paths.d/git
   1 /etc/paths.d/git
$ cat /etc/paths.d/git
/usr/local/git/bin
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I've changed networks again as I'm visiting some friends but everything seems to be back in working order.